# Angular2 not rendering "static" text on page loads

Tags: google-chrome, angular, chromium

So this is kinda difficult to explain so I have a [sort video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFgUWBqrDp8) of the issue with annotations

It seems like static text is not rendering (see the **H3 tag**). The dynamic stuff like `{{ foo.bar }}` and things in loops seem to work fine. It is happening to all pages as far as I can tell.

I used the [AngularClass](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) repo as a starting point.

When the page is loaded directly or refreshed (F5 etc)
[image: how it should be]

When its accessed via a link from another page
[image: no static text]

template file

```
<h3>GPS raw data</h3>
<div class="row" *ngIf="gps && gps.location">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <strong>Time:</strong> {{ gps.location.timestamp }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <strong>Latitude:</strong> {{ gps.location.latitude }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <strong>Longitude:</strong> {{ gps.location.longitude }}
    </div>
</div>
```

There is no errors in the console.

### edit

Another image to possibly clear up what the actual problem is. Note the HTML has content in the title, its hard coded. But its not displayed.

[image]

Comment: What is the issue. Even after watching the video ,I can't understand.

Comment: Did you have annotations on? it explains step by step in the annotations. Anyway, see the latest image I have added.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** 1st solution,  it should be **`*ngIf`** and not **`ng-if`**

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="gps && gps.location">                    //<<<===here
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <strong>Time:</strong> {{ gps.location.timestamp }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <strong>Latitude:</strong> {{ gps.location.latitude }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <strong>Longitude:</strong> {{ gps.location.longitude }}
    </div>
</div>
```

**2)** 2nd solution, don't use **`*ngIf`** and use **`?.`** operator as shown below,

```
<div class="row" > 
    <div class="col-md-4" >
        <strong>Time:</strong> {{ gps?.location.timestamp }}      //<<<==here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <strong>Latitude:</strong> {{ gps?.location.latitude }}   //<<<==here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <strong>Longitude:</strong> {{ gps?.location.longitude }} //<<<==here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the ngIf has been changed, but that is not the problem. Please see the updated image. Its nothing to do with the template variables. Its the static text that is not showing.

Comment: damn, its working fine in firefox. Has the same buggy behaviour in chrome (what I was using) and chromium.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on Chrome and fixed it by removing the `font-size` style applied on that element. Not sure why, might be a bug of Chrome.